# preg_replace with array index

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have an associative array, and a text with variables names inside, surrounded with brackets like this :

```
$message = "The value of var is: {var} ...-";
```

My array is like this:

```
$array=array('var'=>$var);
```

(Obviously this array can be bigger, and I don't know the name of the variables inside of it). Here is what I'm trying to do: I want to replace the {var} in my message by it's value in my array, like this:

```
$newMessage = preg_replace('#\{(.+)\}#',$array["$1"],$message);
```

Anyone knows how to do it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Take a look at: `preg_replace_callback()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@Rizier123's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510106/preg-replace-with-array-index#comment56761329_34510106) helped me, here's the code I used to solve my problem:

```
$newMessage=preg_replace_callback('#\{(.+)\}#',function($match)use($array){
    return $array[$match[1]];
},$message);
```